# How to add div after svg to an existing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have below div(mainDiv) in my html .

```
<div id="mainDiv">  
<svg ></svg>
</div>
```

Now I want to add one more div(lastDiv) to this div as shown below

```
    <div id="mainDiv">
    <svg ></svg>
    <div id="lastDiv"> </div>
    </div>
```

I tried like $("#mainDiv").append(lastDiv);

But it is appending before the svg as shown below.

```
    <div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="lastDiv"> </div>
    <svg ></svg>
    </div>
```

But I need as follows:

```
    <div id="mainDiv">
    <svg ></svg>
    <div id="lastDiv"> </div>
   </div>
```

can you please help me on this.

Comment: its working fine https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/4350/

Comment: yes, your code should be working right. Please check again.

Comment: My code is adding the lastdiv before the svg element

Answer (score 0):

[Best explained here](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)

```
$( lastDiv ).insertAfter( "svg " );
```

before the `.insertAfter` you type what you need to insert after and after the  `.insertAfter` you type after what it needs to be inserted